# convert a bash script to python3

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have a bash script, which is running perfectly:

```
gvim  --servername "servername" $1
if [ -f ${1%.tex}.pdf ];
then
  evince ${1%.tex}.pdf &
fi
evince_vim_dbus.py  GVIM servername ${1%.tex}.pdf  $1 &
```

I am trying to convert it to python as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import call
import sys, os

inp_tex = sys.argv[1]
oup_pdf = os.path.splitext(sys.argv[1])[0]+".pdf"
print(oup_pdf)

call(["gvim", "--servername", "servername",  sys.argv[1]])

if os.path.exists(oup_pdf):
  call(["evince", oup_pdf])

call(["evince_vim_dbus.py", "GVIM", "servername", oup_pdf, inp_tex])
```

in the python, both gvim and evince window is open, but `evince_vim_dbus.py` line is not working. Not that it is giving any error, but it is not showing intended result, as it should, and is doing with the bash script.

trying with **check_call** (I have to kill it after a while, here's the traceback):

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/rudra/vims.py", line 28, in <module>
    check_call(["python","/home/rudra/bin/evince_vim_dbus.py", "GVIM", "servername", oup_pdf, inp_tex])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 576, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 559, in call
    return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1658, in wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1608, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: `call(["gvim", "--servername", "'servername'",  sys.argv[1]])`: there are single quotes within double quotes, is that a typo?

Comment: can you check return code of the commands? and why calling a python script inside another when importing is so easy?

Comment: I am running Linux

Comment: done! single quotes are removed.

Comment: BTW, your original bash actually has a bunch of bugs -- try using it to process a file with spaces in its name to see. Consider running it through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the problems identified.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the bash file works, and the python script uses `call` in a way that protects the spaces. One common mistake avoided.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, ...the bash file works **only with names not having spaces or wildcards**. Which is to say, in the common case only. Which is to say, it has bugs. You're correct, the Python version doesn't have those bugs; you'll note that I never made any contrary claim.

Comment: @BaRud: now you _have_ to print the return code of your commands: `rc = call ...` and print them. Because it's very likely that one of them fail. Or replace `call` by `check_call` which checks return status.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree: the bash file has bugs. But the point is to rewrite it in python, and then the bug you're mentionning goes away.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, sure -- for this one script. Presumably the OP still writes bash for other things on occasion; it'd be worth having a chance to learn good practices regardless. (And misunderstanding semantics of the origin language is part of what led to the double-quoting, for example; improving knowledge is a Good Thing in general).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know you're always giving good advice about bash.

Comment: @BaRud: try last line as `check_call(["python","evince_vim_dbus.py", "GVIM", "servername", oup_pdf, inp_tex])`. And tell me: does your script end, or just hangs?

Comment: It stays as it is, and when i kill it, outputs those lines

Comment: good. Can you show us the `evince_vim_dbus.py` now?

Comment: Hi, I think, I got the source of error, but don't know how to fix it. after the call to evince, its not going forward.  `if os.path.exists(oup_pdf):
  call(["evince", oup_pdf])

print("hello")` does not print hello

Comment: @BaRud: That's exactly what the last paragraph of my answer says.

Comment: dolda2000: correct.

Comment: just have converted call to popen and its done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to have a guess that your real problem isn't the `evince_vim_dbus.py` line itself, but rather the `gvim` line, because you pass it the server name `'servername'` instead of simply `servername`, and so doesn't match the name on the line that runs `evince_vim_dbus.py`.

I'm not familiar with gvim or its server functionality, but I'm guessing the `evince_vim_dbus.py` program connects to gvim using the given name, in which case it's going to fail since the server of the right name isn't running.

If that's not it, then maybe the problem is that `subprocess.call()` runs the given program and waits for it to exit, whereas in your original bash script, you run `evince` with an ampersand, causing bash not to wait for it, so maybe the problem is that `evince_vim_dbus.py` never runs at all until you exit Evince.

Comment: I have `gvim  --servername "servername" $1` in bash, with "severname" under quote.

Comment: @BaRud, sure but those quotes are consumed by bash and aren't passed into gvim. In fact, those quotes were no-ops and completely extraneous.

Comment: Tried this: `call(["gvim", "--servername", "servername",  sys.argv[1]])`, with no result.

Comment: @BaRud, ...to be clear, those quotes are *syntactic* in bash -- they're instructions to the shell, not passed to `gvim` in the argv array used in the `execv`-family syscall that does the actual heavy lifting of starting an external command. Because you don't have any shell when using `subprocess.call()` in this manner (and *don't* add `shell=True`, that's creating more problems!), there's nothing for those quotes to be parsed/consumed by.